# Pass storyboard names into a switch statement?

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, switch-statement

Can I make the name of the view the parameter for a switch statement? If so what would I use in the switch?

```
[self addChildViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View1"]];
[self addChildViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View2"]];
[self addChildViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View3"]];
[self addChildViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View4"]];
[self addChildViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View5"]];
[self addChildViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View6"]];
[self addChildViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View7"]];
[self addChildViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View8"]];
[self addChildViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View9"]];
[self addChildViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View10"]];
```

Depending on the view name I want to display a different bit of text in a label. So I want a switch where the cases are the name of the views I just don't know how to return the name of the views so I can check against them.

Thanks.

Comment: If you have the name _in a string_ already, you don't need a switch. If you're trying to get the label of a _variable_ at runtime, well, you can do it for ivars, but it's almost certainly the wrong way to go. Please elaborate on what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass NSString to a switch statement in objective C without getting the following error.

> error: statement requires expression of integer type ('NSString *' invalid)

Use an if statement instead and check isEqualToString

Comment: How would I get the name of the view to check this?

Comment: Its not the name of the view actually, its the identifier of the segue that you set in interface builder.  [segue identifier] will get the name off the segue.

Comment: Yeah, it's defined in Storyboard id in ib. Still can't return it

Comment: in pseudo it would be if (controlleridentifer name == View1) then title = title1. elseif (viewcontrolleridentifer name = View2) then title = title2 and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You could switch an NSNumber's intValue (`switch ([num intValue]) {`) that represents the numeric part of the ViewController's name and then name it like (suppose 'num' your NSNumber previously set):

```
[self addChildViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"View%d", num]]];
```

Comment: You can't switch on an object, only an integral type.

Comment: Well, I didn't remember to say that the switch would be with '[num intValue]', for example.